# Naming context and ejb-jar in TomEE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, ejb-3.0, apache-tomee

I'm getting an NamingContext.lookup error trying to find `ejb/ebj001ini` that I can't solve. The configuration is as follows:

Bean: `iportal.Sp001iniB.java`

Ejb-jar.xml: (tried placing it in META-INF and WEB-INF, getting the same error)

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <display-name>ejb000ini</display-name>
      <ejb-name>ejb000ini</ejb-name>
      <home>iportal.Sp000iniH</home>
      <remote>iportal.Sp000iniS</remote>
      <ejb-class>iportal.Sp000iniB</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>

  <assembly-descriptor>
    <container-transaction>
      <method>
        <ejb-name>ejb000ini</ejb-name>
        <method-name>*</method-name>
      </method>
      <trans-attribute>Supports</trans-attribute>
    </container-transaction>
  </assembly-descriptor>
```

Servlet that calls initialize the EJB:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Sp000iniH ih = (Sp000iniH)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/ejb000ini");
Sp000ini myEjb = ih.create();
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried declare the bean-name as "ejb/ejb000ini"? OR do the lookup as : c.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb000ini").

Comment: I´ve tried both, but none works.. also changing all the names to SpXXXini.. I´m lost

Comment: will be easier if you provide some code like the: interfaces and the ejb declaration

Comment: I finally gave up and started using a ejb-jar 3.0 description instead of 2.1.

Comment: In a .war file, the deployment descriptor is stored with the name WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml. For .jar is stored in the META-INF folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused with your deployment desc, if your using TOMEE are you using EJB 3.x isn't?, in this the case try to use the ejb 3.x version of the descriptor, here you could find an example > http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-stateless-with-descriptor/README.html

Comment: No, i'm not using ejb3.x. That's the problem. I would like to deploy an old app that uses ejb 2.0 descriptors in tomee. As i could not get it working, i'm now trying to rewrite the old ejb into Ejb3.0. I've made some test and they seem to work, hopefully the whole app works also and it just take me a few days.